# Send email to multiple addresses from database

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to make a little contact form, in which I can send an email to multiple users in a database, I am trying to just select all the emails then use a while loop to send to each one, however it is only sending to the first email in my database and not the rest.. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $body= $_POST['body'];
  $subject= $_POST['subject'];
  $user = $_SESSION["name"];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $user";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $email = $row["contact_email"];
      mail($email, $subject, $body,'From: myemail@gmail.com');
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a database table per user, you should take a good look at your database design again because that doesn't sound right.

Comment: `print_r($row["contact_email"])` Check what's the output. and @jeroen is completely right. Are creating table for each user?

Comment: @jeroen I know it's not good, but I could not think of any other way to do it :(

Comment: @kinshuk Lahiri that prints all the email addresses in my database

Comment: @dfarrelly Surely, there is a better way. You can create a user's table for all the users. And also, where you placed the `print_r()` i told?

Comment: I have got a user table that contains all the registered user, But each user has an email list which is contained in a separate table if you get me?

Comment: I'm not so sure how this even works, but are you sure this is correct `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $user";` !? the `$user` variable has the name of the table?

Comment: I actually just got all the emails, they just took a long time to come through on the remaining email addresses

Comment: You mean to say that all the emails are stored inside one table right?

Comment: whats your user-table's name?

Comment: I have a user_details table which contains user_id, user_name, user_email and user_password and then for each of these users I have a separate table named after the user  which contains all their contacts, so $user is the name of the logged in user

Comment: take a look here, i've build a sample schema you can use as a reference for your project, as it should be if you said that a user can have more emails

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a950e/1

Comment: Thank you @Cristian, so I just store the email lists of every user in one table?

Comment: Exactly, every row points to another row in the first table as you can see there is the references keyword

Comment: So let me make the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following tables:

### Users

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Boss  |
|  2 | Boris |
+----+-------+
create table users(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 name varchar(255) not null
);
```

### Emails

```
+---------+-----------------+
| user_id |      email      |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | boss1@boss.com  |
|       1 | boss2@boss.com  |
|       1 | boss3@boss.com  |
|       2 | boris1@boss.com |
|       2 | boris2@boss.com |
+---------+-----------------+

create table emails(
 user_id int references users(id),
 email varchar(255) not null
);
```

Pay attention to the reference that the **user_id** has to the **users** table.

Now in PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $body = $_POST['body'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $user = mysqli::real_escape_string($_SESSION["name"]);

  $result = $conn->query("SELECT id from users where name='".$user."'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $user_id = intval($row["id"]);

  $sql = "SELECT email FROM emails where user_id=".$user_id;
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $email = $row["email"];
      mail($email, $subject, $body,'From: myemail@gmail.com');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cristian, just one question how would I go about inserting an email into the Emails database? I'm just not familiar with using reference, could you give me a sample insert statement?

Comment: INSERT INTO emails SET email="mail@boss.com", user_id=1;

Comment: pay attention that you have to put a user_id that exists in the users table